# Fetch API default cross-origin behavior

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

The [Fetch Specifications](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode) say that the default Fetch mode is 'no-cors' -

> A request has an associated mode, which is "same-origin", "cors", "no-cors", "navigate", or "websocket". Unless stated otherwise, it is "no-cors".

But, I seem to be noticing this behavioral difference between `mode: 'no-cors'` and an unspecified mode. As demonstrated in this [JSFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/a26x6tck/1/), explicitly defining mode as 'no-cors' makes the response inaccessible to the Javascript, while not specifying a mode makes the Response object available to the calling method.

Does explicitly specifying the fetch mode work differently from the default behavior that internally uses the same mode? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`no-cors` is only the default for the base Fetch algorithm. But in various other places in the spec, that algorithm gets called into with a specific mode stated other than `no-cors`. In particular, for cross-origin requests, the algorithm gets called with the mode set to `cors`.

More specifically, for cross-origin requests, the Fetch algorithm sets the [“response tainting”](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-response-tainting) for the request to `cors` and requires the fetch to be performed using the [CORS protocol](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol).

And even more specifically, see the following substeps of step 12 of the [“Main fetch” algorithm](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#main-fetch):

> ↪ ***request*’s current url’s origin is same origin with *request*’s
> origin and *CORS flag* is unset**
> ↪ **request’s current url’s scheme is "`data`"**
> ↪ **request’s mode is "`navigate`" or "`websocket`"**
>
> 1. Set request’s response tainting to "`basic`".
> 2. Return the result of performing a scheme fetch using *request*.
>    …
>
> ↪ ***request*’s mode is "`no-cors`"**
>
> 1. Set *request*’s response tainting to "`opaque`".
> 2. Return the result of performing a scheme fetch using *request*.
>    …
>
> ↪ **Otherwise**
>
> 1. Set request’s response tainting to "`cors`".
> 2. Return the result of performing an HTTP fetch using request with *CORS flag* set.

What it amounts to is, if the request URL isn’t same-origin with your code’s origin, the scheme isn’t `data`, and the mode isn’t `navigate` or `websocket` or isn’t explicitly set to `no-cors`, then that **Otherwise** condition gets reached, and the request gets made using the [CORS protocol](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol).

That explanation simplifies things a bit because in the case where the request has properties that trigger the browser to do a preflight, there’s a substep just above that *Otherwise* substep that gets reached instead—but again in that case, the “response tainting” gets set to `cors`.

> But, I seem to be noticing this behavioral difference between `mode: 'no-cors'` and an unspecified mode.

The difference is because when you explicitly set `no-cors` mode for the request, in that case the *“↪ request’s mode is "no-cors"”* substep gets reached instead of the *Otherwise* substep.

> As demonstrated in this JSFiddle sample, explicitly defining mode as 'no-cors' makes the response inaccessible to the Javascript,

Right—that’s because it causes the *“↪ request’s mode is "no-cors"”* substep in the “Main fetch” algorithm to get reached instead of the *Otherwise* substep.

> while not specifying a mode makes the Response object available to the calling method.

Because the *Otherwise* substep does then get reached, so a CORS-enabled fetch gets made.

> Does explicitly specifying the fetch mode work differently from the default behavior that internally uses the same mode?

Yes, for a cross-origin request, explicitly setting `mode: 'no-cors'` forces the request to be made without using CORS, while leaving it unspecified causes it to be made using CORS.

That *“Unless stated otherwise, it is "`no-cors`"”* statement about the mode definitely isn’t meant to specify that requests that get made using the `fetch(…)` method without an explicit mode specified end up having their mode locked into `no-cors`.