# How can I fix this image download error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, imagedownload

This is my code:

```
function downloadImage(url) {
  fetch(url, {
  mode: 'no-cors',
  })
   .then(response => response.blob())
   .then(blob => {
       let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       let a = document.createElement('a');
       a.download = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
       a.href = blobUrl;
       document.body.appendChild(a);
       a.click();
       a.remove();
       })
}

var url = 'https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/203/636/834/minimalism-landscape-digital- 
windows-11-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg';

downloadImage(url)
```

i can successfully download the image but when I open the image it's shows **Sorry, Photos can't open this file because the format is currently unsupported, or the file is corrupted**

When I use unsplash image url in that time it's work well. Can anyone tell me please why it's happening and how can I fix this issue.

Comment: The format unsupported error can arise due to a variety of reasons , the most usual suspect in my opinion is :

The [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)  **Response** header being of some other MIME type.

What is the value of the Content-Type header in the response of the `fetch` ?

Comment: Sir can you please elaborate what you asking for  because I didn't understand that

Comment: Follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/how-can-i-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome) to open Dev tools and look at the **Response Headers** field of the Network request to the **_url_**, we are interested in the `Content-Type` header and what is its value.

Comment: content-type: image/jpeg sir....

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is the `Response` object , `fetch` is being called with **mode:'no-cors'**, resulting in the `response` object to have `type` as `"opaque"` and hence using `response.blob()` will result into a Blob size of `0` and Blob type of `""` (read more below in Response.blob()).

The mime-type is set as expected and your code works as expected but since you are making a cross origin request you are getting Response.blob() as *empty* and the file you subsequently save(*download* through anchor tag) has no data.

[Read more about Response.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob)

[Read more about Response.type](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#response_types)

[Read more about CORS Protocol](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol)

to validate the above try and console.log the blob like so :

```
function downloadImage(url) {
  fetch(url, {
  mode: 'no-cors',
  })
   .then(response => response.blob())
   .then(blob => {
       console.log(blob); //log the blob and check its size;
       let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       let a = document.createElement('a');
       a.download = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
       a.href = blobUrl;
       document.body.appendChild(a);
       a.click();
       a.remove();
       })
}
```

Comment: Further, to understand how to use cross origin images on img tags and canvas [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) is a great read.

Comment: then what is the ideal solution? not using 'no-cors' is showing a failed to fetch error

Answer (score 0):

Do like this because you're not defining MIME type while downloading the file.

```
return fetch(urlEndpoint, options)
  .then((res) => res.blob())
  .then((blob) => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  .then((href) => {
    Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {
      href,
      download: 'filename.png',
    }).click();
  });
```

or else you can do like this

```
download(filename,url) {
     fetch(url, { 
  mode: 'no-cors',
  })
     .then(response => response.blob())
     .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
     .then(uril => {
     var link = document.createElement("a");
     link.href = uril;
     link.download = filename + ".png";
     document.body.appendChild(link);
     link.click();
     document.body.removeChild(link);
     });
 }
```

Comment: Do I type filename with extension like myimage.jpg or without extension like myimage sir?

Comment: Ya you have to define extension with image name like this forestpic.jpg you can see the second code above the answer and don't forget mark this right answer!! @anjanna

Comment: Sir getting same error...

Comment: This error ?? Sorry, Photos can't open this file because the format is currently unsupported, or the file is corrupted  @anjanna

Comment: yes sir Sorry, Photos can't open this file because the format is currently unsupported, or the file is corrupted....

Comment: As I checked now, that's CORS error maybe you have to do server side or else you can use this [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) @anjanna

Comment: Sir does it possible to do that from client side???

Comment: Right now I don't know that much but, you can use [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) deploy this code on Heroku and use it like this `'https://url-cors-url.xyz/https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/203/636/834/minimalism-landscape-digital-windows-11-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg'` @anjanna